# Redimensionar campos de Tabla Acess una vez creada a través de .net

Tags: vb.net, .net

necesito redimensionar ciertos campos de una tabla Access que ya está creada, sin tener que volver a borrar la tabla y volver a crear los campos. 
Quisiera hacerlo a través de codigo .NET // Visual 
Sería posible ? 
Gracias.

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia, pero ¿no puedes abrir el fichero access y cambiar el tamaño de los campos que necesites?

Comment: No una vez se han introducido datos en ella.

Comment: Si es para aumentarlo, no pasa nada, les cambias el tamaño y listo. De todas formas, antes de hacer nada, haz una copia por si las moscas.

Comment: Puedes utilizar el comando [`ALTER TABLE`](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Instrucci%C3%B3n-ALTER-TABLE-81d241e3-1522-4103-acf0-9857888d581c) para modificar el tamaño de una columna. El formato sería algo asi como `ALTER TABLE tabla ALTER COLUMN nombrecolumna TEXT(10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te ha dicho Fernando Forcén, si es una cuestion puntual puedes simplemente abrir la base de datos con el Access y modificar el tamaño del campo. Mientras sea para aumentarlo, no debería haber ningun problema.

Si realmente necesitas hacerlo por código, puedes utilizar el comando SQL [`ALTER TABLE`](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Instrucci%C3%B3n-ALTER-TABLE-81d241e3-1522-4103-acf0-9857888d581c) para modificarlo. Te doy un ejemplo de la manera de hacerlo:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\tubasededatos.mdb");
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("ALTER TABLE tuTabla ALTER COLUMN columna TEXT(tamaño)", conn);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias !! Ha funcionado